VBA to copy consecutive clicked single cells
I'm attempting to make a PTO calculator, in which a user would click a date or set of dates and the spreadsheet would spit out what the remaining PTO balance would be if vacation time was taken during those days. I'd like the dates & values that were selected to remain present on the sheet if the month changes, so that someone could hypothetically plan a full year ahead. Screenshot of what this looks like below.
This is the VBA I've written so far, which takes a single selected date and copies it over the side, where someone could enter how many hours they'd like to take that day (1.0-8.0).The goal being that the dates would present themselves in a linear/easy to read fashion next to the calendar, all with a single click.
(Sorry, formatting was a little weird. And I've been adding & deleting pieces of it so it's probably messy in general.)
So basically I just need this action to repeat n times, each time copying the date one more cell to the right, which I'm having trouble conceptualizing. Any guidance would be appreciated!
I can also share the workbook itself if that would be helpful.

        Dim originalCell As Range

        Sub CopyAndReturn()

        Dim currentCell As Range
        Dim destinationCell As Range

        Set originalCell = ActiveCell

    Range("C10:I15").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("D18").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

    Application.Goto originalCell
        
    Set currentCell = ActiveCell
    
    currentCell.Offset(8, 0).Select
    
    Set destinationCell = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("L10")
        destinationCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value
    Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
   
        Range("L11").Select
   
   
        End Sub




Side note: You want to avoid using Select in your code.

It's not clear exactly what's going on in your posted code.  What is the copy/paste for?  And the range being copied doesn't correspond to your screenshot's calendar location.

@TimWilliams the copy area was a typo - fixed now. The Copy/Paste is because the calendar is populated via an array formula, so every value not in C10 is a Spill, and I can't therefore copy or reference them to pull a date value. Or at least I'm not aware that it's an option. Hopefully I'm explaining that correctly.

Here's what I'd maybe do:
Sub AddVacationDates()

    Dim c As Range, rng As Range, ws As Worksheet, okSel As Boolean
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Calendar")
    
    If Selection.Parent.Name = ws.Name Then 'make sure we're on the correct sheet....
        Set rng = Application.Intersect(Selection, ws.Range("C10:I15"))
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then       'selection inside calendar range?
            For Each c In rng.Cells      'check each selected cell inside the calendar
                If Len(c.Value) > 0 Then 'cell has a value?
                    With ws.Cells(10, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).offset(0, 1) 'next empty cell in "Selected dates"
                        .NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
                        .Value = c.Value
                    End With
                    okSel = True 'flag at least one date was captured
                End If
            Next c
        End If
    End If
    
    If Not okSel Then 'nothing copied over?
        MsgBox "You must first select one or more dates in the calendar!", _
                vbInformation, "No dates selected"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
End Sub

